# 'OnWillpop' is not working when 'TextFormfield' is in focus in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Facing issue with the handling of `onWillPop` method as I am using this method to handle Android back button functionality. I have `TextFormField` on my screen, so when I don't select this field or not take focus on it , `onWillPop` method is working means what exit code I have written it works and user is successfully exit from app on Android back button click.

But when I edit 'TextFormField' or take focus on it and then click on Android back button, then `onWillPop` method is not get called.

I am using beta 1.22 pre flutter version.

Please Help
Thanks

Comment: onWillPop is not called, or the content inside onWillPop is not run? Like, when you and print("check"); before anything inside onWillPop, does it get printed out?